# Convert String to Float::INFINITY

Tags: ruby, types, floating-point, numbers

In *Ruby* `Float::INFINITY.to_s` results in `"Infinity"` and `"Infinity".to_f` results in `0.0`:

```
irb(main):001:0> Float::INFINITY.to_s
=> "Infinity"
irb(main):002:0> "Infinity".to_f
=> 0.0
```

Why is this the case? Why is the symmetry broken? In the programming language for human beings, I would expect the result of the second statement to be `Float::INFINITY`. Is there any way to convert a string to `Float::INFINITY` or `-Float::INFINITY` with *Ruby*?

---

Btw. maybe related: The behavior of `to_json` in Rails is confusing as well. I'd expect it to raise like `ActiveModel::Serializer#as_json` does.

```
irb(main):001:0> {a: Float::INFINITY}.to_json
=> "{\"a\":null}"
```

Comment: `[1,2,3].to_s.to_a` doesn't work either.

Comment: This is a valid point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the question of why the design decision was made so that infinity breaks the symmetry:

```
Float::INFINITY.to_s.to_f # => 0.0
```

The reason is - it's the only way to have consistency. The promise that `#to_f` gives you is that it will interpret the float **literal** in (at the start of) the string.

---

`Infinity` isn't a **literal**. If you try to evaluate it, you will get:

> `NameError`: uninitialized constant `Infinity`

`Float::INFINITY` isn't a **literal** either. It's the constant `INFINITY` nested under `Float`.

Why does it have to be only literals then? Well... I can make `#to_s` return anything:

```
class Float
  def to_s
    'foo'
  end
end

42.0.to_s # => 'foo'
```

Obviously it's both impossible and unreasonable to expect `'foo'.to_f` to return `42.0`.

We can make `Float::INFINITY.to_s` return other stuff. The string `'Infinity'` isn't in any way special. It's not a float **literal** like `-1.23` or `9.999999999999995e+39`.

---

You can look at it the opposite way - most floats when `#to_s`-ed return a string representing their **literal** form. It's only a happy coincidence that that's also what you need to `#to_f` them back. `Float::INFINITY` doesn't return the string version of the **literal** form, because it has no **literal** form.

---

That's all. While I think an awesome opportunity was missed to make `∞` "the infinity literal", they probably saved themselves a lot of headache by not adding a unicode character as a requirement to have the complete language grammar.

Can you think of any programming language that has literal syntax for infinity?

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

The way `#to_f` works is it tries to find a float at the beginning of the string (ignoring whitespaces). It ignores the rest. If it doesn't find anything "floaty-literal-looking", it defaults to `0.0`. That's why:

```
''.to_f         # => 0.0
'∞'.to_f        # => 0.0
'foo'.to_f      # => 0.0
'foo 1.23'.to_f # => 0.0
' 1.23'.to_f    # => 1.23
'1.23foo'.to_f  # => 1.23
```

The string `'Infinity'` is no different from any other letter only string in that regard. This is kind of unfortunate as it breaks the symmetry. As you pointed out:

```
Float::INFINITY.to_s.to_f # => 0.0
```

But at the same time if `'Infinity'` did parse to `Float::INFINITY` this could have lead to some fairly weird and hard to track bugs in everyday code.

---

Obviously don't do it, but for completeness' sake - to answer the last part:

> Is there any way to convert a string to Float::INFINITY or -Float::INFINITY with Ruby?

```
eval('Float::INFINITY')  # => Float::INFINITY
eval('-Float::INFINITY') # => -Float::INFINITY
```

Comment: Thank you @ndenkov. I would've guessed that. Do you know why Ruby decides to break the symmetry? Is this simply to be more approachable to programmers coming from other domains? Because well: my human expectation would be that we have this symmetry.

Comment: @schmijos I misunderstood the question. The question wasn't really why that happens, more why this design decision was made. I posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60975688/2423164) in order to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer on the second part of your question (the first part is brilliantly answered by @ndnenkov), and leaving aside if it is a good or bad idea (as pointed out again by @ndnenkov), a way to avoid an eval on a string can be something like this:

```
class String
  SPECIAL_FLOATS = {
    Float::INFINITY.to_s => Float::INFINITY,
    (-Float::INFINITY).to_s => -Float::INFINITY
  }

  alias_method :super_to_f, :to_f

  def to_f
    if String::SPECIAL_FLOATS.key? self
      return String::SPECIAL_FLOATS[self]
    else
      return self.super_to_f
    end
  end
end

"Infinity".to_f
# => Float::INFINITY
Float::INFINITY.to_s.to_f
# => Float::INFINITY
```

extending the String class in such a way it can handle the conversion of some special Float literals. If it is a good idea or not is a quite complex topic, and in some way it depends on your project and how you are using strings across your code.

---

Just for comparison, in ruby 2.5.3 on Windows (and not rails, thus `require "JSON"`):

```
{a: Float::INFINITY}.to_json
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#         3: from C:/tools/ruby25/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
#         2: from (irb):43
#         1: from (irb):43:in `to_json'
# JSON::GeneratorError (862: Infinity not allowed in JSON)
```

Comment: Wow! I like Ruby so much!

Comment: I really like the syntax. I used quite a lot in the past, not so much nowadays, and I'm missing it

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to convert a string to Float::INFINITY or -Float::INFINITY with Ruby?

You can use [`Object#const_get`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_get) for it:

```
:001 > Float::INFINITY
 => Infinity
:002 > string = Float::INFINITY.to_s
 => "Infinity"
:003 > Object.const_get("Float::#{string.upcase}")
 => Infinity
```

Comment: I like the way you think, but isn't this a bit risky?

Comment: @schmijos May I ask you clarify a bit, what you mean by 'risky'? :)
`#const_get` just selects needed constant from `Object` constants space, you can check it by `Object.constants`, I can't imagine any risks of it, to be honest ':)

Comment: I receive the string from the web and would not want anyone to coerce a `Float::NAN`. But anyways, I didn't downvote ;-)

Comment: @schmijos Using of params from the web in meta-programming without any validations of is always risky ':)
You can add any simple validation like lines: 1. `return unless some_web_param.match /infinity/i`; 2. `do some magic with 'some_web_param'` :)

Comment: @schmijos I don't worry about downvotes without any comments on it ':)